# What other words/terms are used to mean 'sleep'?

Tags: single-word-requests

Are there alternative words to 'sleep,' when used as a noun to mean 'the substance that sometimes forms in the corners of your eyes after you have been sleeping?' Are 'eye crust,' 'eye boogers,' 'eye gunk,' 'eye goop,' 'optibooger,' 'sleepy,' or 'gound' acceptable? 
It seems most dictionaries such as Oxford, Cambridge, Longman, Macmillan, Merriam-Webster, etc., don't include most of those words/terms. Why?

Comment: +1 for brilliant question! Everyone knows *snot* and *boogers* (British *bogeys*), and most of us have at least one more *(greenies, pickings, etc.)* for nasal debris, but there's not really a dedicated single word for eye crud. I mainly hear/use *sleep, sleepies, sleepers* nowadays, but as kids me and my peers just called it "eye" because nobody had a better word.

Comment: Not really relevant, but having just discovered it's a British-only usage, I can't resist throwing in [(Green) Gilbert](http://www.encyclo.co.uk/define/Green%20Gilbert) as one of our synonyms for "snot".

Answer (score 3):

The actual medical term is **[rheum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rheum)** (which applies to nose and mouth excretions that occur during sleep, as well).

"Sleep" is what I grew up saying, but if [Discovery Magazine](http://www.discoverymagazine.com/digger/d01dd/d0101dd.html) is any guide, kids now say "crusties" as well. (The article also describes the organ responsible, if you're curious.)

*Sleep* always kind of creeped me out for being vague (and euphemisms generally unsettled me, making me feel like the actual thing was unspeakable), and "crusties" and "eye boogers" seem too childish now.

I think *eye gunk* is clear and not cloyingly juvenile; it gets my vote.

Comment: While we're on the topic, there's the stuff you find between your toes if you don't wash your feet often enough.

Comment: @Barrie England: That's a whole nother question! As would be navel debris, ear scrapings, fingernail pickings, and (dare I say it?) [smegma](http://dictionary.webmd.com/terms/smegma). Ugh.

Comment: We called that toe jam!

Comment: Euphemisms unsettle you? I've never heard that one before.

Comment: @Jeremy They still do, yes. In my mind, few things are so bad they can't be spoken of directly; if others feel the need to avoid telling something like it is, I'm forced to wonder a) *Why are they so freaked out about that mundane reality?* and/or b) *Do they see something (horrible) I don't see?*

Answer (score 1):

I knew it as *sleepy dust* when I was a child.